# Implementing an operation without operators

Tags: algorithm, architecture, language-agnostic, system

There are many interview questions like

> implement addition without using +,-,*,/

My question isn't about how to do one of these but rather: what is the **practical use** of those questions?

Are there systems which do not support addition? Or is there another particular circumstance I should be aware of?

Comment: I guess they are just examples of algorithms that everyone already knows from school. So people can concentrate on implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical use I can see is if the company designs circuits or microcode for adders.  While it is useful from a theoretical perspective to know how addition is performed on binary numbers, software developers are more concerned about operator precedence (addition after multiplication after exponentiation after parentheses, etc.)

Maybe it is useful to see if the programmer knows how bit operators work but if the language supports addition then there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

For most software development jobs out there, I would say this question has no practical use.  Finding a good fit with the toolset and culture is way more important.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mixture of theoretical and practical here.

If it's specifically about implementing addition, it's probably at least mostly theoretical--essentially every processor already implements addition perfectly well.

If, however, it were about implementing multiplication or division there's at least a possibility of some practical application--some of the smaller embedded processors do *not* have multiplication or division instructions. Likewise operations like square roots, transcendental functions like sine and cosine, etc.

In fairness, I should probably add that even among people writing code on such small systems, probably only a fairly small percentage ever write *this* kind of code. In most cases, if the processor doesn't implement multiplication and division directly, most people are still going to write code in something like C that can assume they exist, and those operations will be implemented by the compiler and/or standard library.

Some of these also become interesting for things like implementing libraries to support arbitrary precision integers. Again, the number of people who need to do this on a regular basis is pretty small though--there are already a fair number of such libraries around for most languages, so it's pretty rare that anybody needs to re-implement one from the ground up.

Another place it can arise is if you work for a company that actually designs and builds microprocessors. Such companies typically need highly accurate behavioral models of their microprocessors, including bit-accurate simulations of all the processor's instructions, not just "well, what we produce looks pretty similar to what Intel produces", or something on that order.

Even putting all these together, I think you still end up with a fairly small niche though.

Comment: plus one for arbitrary precision integers

Answer (score -1):

There's no need for the intrinsic nature of the question to be useful.

The purpose of the question is to find something out about the interviewee in a limited time. The real work he is going to do will take hours and days, we ask him to do something that we believe contains the essence of his possible work that we can evaluate in a short time. For example: can he solve a problem he has not seen before? Can he explain things clearly? does he have a problem solving attitude?